# how to populate ${moduleName}, ${value}, ${key} values dynamically in url using requestPromise in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request-promise

I am using request-promise to get data from http url

```
const request = require("request-promise");
const reqData = async url => {
  try {
    return await request({ url, json: true });
  } catch (e) {
    log.error(`error in getting data from ${url}`, { error: e });
    return new Error(e);
  }
};
```

I want to populate these values dynamically ${moduleName}, ${value}, ${key} using this url.

```
url =  https://example.com/api/$moduleName}/en/${value}?apikey=${key}
```

But I m getting this url from s3 bucket.

```
const s3Response = await s3ReadFile(bucketName, fileName);
const urlObject = JSON.parse(s3Response);
const result = await request.reqData(urlObject.url);
```

Please help.

Comment: And where are those values for the placeholders coming from?

Comment: @JackBashford edited my question, placeholders are from my method where I m using my url.